# How to permanently ban an ip address that has established an ssh connection to a unbuntu 16.04/nginx server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security

I have a vps setup with simple fail2ban settings to keep from brute force attacks.  However in my tcptrack monitor I see an IP that establishes several connections to my server.  The TCPTrack shows that the ip address is "ESTABLISHED" through port 22.

The address 116.31.116.17 is shown several times with an established connection.  I have tried to ban this ip address with:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 116.31.116.17 -j DROP
```

But it still shows up in tcptrack after I reset the server.  I looked up this address in iplookup and it's an ip address from china.  Not sure how to handle this intrusion.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the complete firewall.

Comment: How is it relevant to nginx?

Comment: -I would be more appropriate than -A, because I suppose there are rules that permit already-established connections. What do you mean by "reset the server"?

Comment: If the same TCP connection stays active for a long period, then it is likely an active and authenticated SSH session. This would mean that your server is compromised and you need to restore it from backups.

Comment: @Law29 I reset the server with sudo service restart nginx

Comment: @Michael Hampton How do I post my firewall?

Comment: So have you tried `/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 116.31.116.17 -j DROP` instead of `-A`? It can take a few minutes for the connection to disappear. Also, of course, @TeroKilkanen is completely right in saying that if this IP has actually obtained access to your server then it is probably corrupted beyond repair . . . and you probably can't trust your logs to say that it did not obtain access. Nginx does not seem to have any relation to your problem at all.

Comment: @Law29 I guess you meant `/sbin/iptables -I INPUT 0 -s 116.31.116.17 -j DROP`? `-I` requires the number for the spot where to insert the rule.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Well yes, I missed the 0, what with iptables-save I'll freely admit to not having needed to use -I in the last ten years or so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server was compromised as you guys stated so I rebuilt another.   I installed tracker again and saw the same ip address attacking again.  Further investigation in /var/log/auth.log revealed a bot trying passwords with root user.  I have now  created a new vps removing root login and also used the iptables ban rule but now it persists when I save it with /sbin/iptables-save.  I didn't realize that servers were so vulnerable from the instant you create them.  Thanks for all the help.